# Algebraic problem solving

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, problem-solving

Let $n$ be a three-digit number and let $m$ be the number obtained by reversing the order of the digits in $n$. Suppose that $m \neq n$ and that $n + m$ and $n − m$ are both divisible by $7$. Find all such pairs $n$ and $m$.

My idea was that you could say
\begin{align}n=100a+10b+c\end{align} where $a$,$b$ and $c$ are digits $0-9$ and $a$ is not zero, 
therefore 
\begin{align}
m &=100c+10b+a \\
n+m &=101a+20b+101c \\
n-m &=99a-99c
\end{align}

If $7$ divides $n-m$ then $7$ divides $99a-99c=99(a-c)$, 
therefore $7$ must divide $a-c$, so the only possible combinations for $a$ and $c$ are $(9,2)$, $(8,1)$ and $(7,0)$ and $(2,9)$, $(1,8)$.

If $7$ divides $n+m=101a+20b+101c$ then $7$ divides $3a-b+3c=3(a+c)-b$.

If $(a,c)=(9,2)$ then $7$ has to divide $3(11)-b=33-b$ which gives $b$ possible values of $5$. 
Solution 1 and 2: $n=952$ or $n=259$.

If $(a,c)=(8,1)$ then $7$ has to divide $3(9)-b=27-b$ which gives $b$ possible values of $6$ .
Solution 3 and 4: $n=861$ or $n=168$.

If $(a,c)=(7,0)$ then $7$ has to divide $3(7)-b=21-b$ which gives $b$ possible values of $0$ or $7$. 
Solution 5: $n=700$. 
Solution 6: $n=770$

Is there any others I have missed?

Comment: I would maybe have felt it more natural to write $3a+6b+3c=3(a+2b+c)$ instead of $3a-b+3c=3(a+c)-b$. Just because you can get rid of the $3$ entirely and things are nicer.

Comment: Writing $n=\overline {abc}$ we remark that $n\equiv 2a+3b+c\pmod 7$.  A little arithmetic then shows that $a\equiv c$ and $b\equiv 5(a+c)$, both $\pmod 7$.  It's now easy to generate all the cases.

Comment: There are no other solutions except the negative ones. Your calculations are correct.

Comment: @Arthur,  Thanks for helping me check my answer.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for helping me check my answer

Comment: @Piquito Thanks for helping me check my answer

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Thanks you for fixing the formatting of my question.